# Angular Material buttons mat-stroked and mat-flat not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material and i am having trouble on displaying 2 types of buttons: the mat-stroked-button and mat-flat-button.

The other buttons are working except these 2. I have imported all the modules needed.

How can i make them work ?

Comment: Have you imported like this `import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';`

Comment: Yes. Every module is added.

Comment: Hi ionuttibi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a [_Minimal, Verifiable Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (such as a StackBlitz or a code snippet) so that we can help you troubleshoot the problem that you’re facing.

Comment: @ionuttibi was this ever fixed? I am having the same issue

Comment: Hello, unfortunately i ditched that project. There might've been a compatibility issue with Angular and current Angular Material version. Try to have them both the same version (eg: Angular v9, Material v9) Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  My global version is 15 but my local version is 13.  All my packages and imported Modules are 13.

Answer (score 5):

You can watch here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26u4pc
both mat-stroked-button and mat-flat-button are working fine.
It will be nice If you share your code.Thank you.